# Unable to draw country level maps using GeoJson in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, vue.js, highcharts

In highcharts maps with Vue, the world map is being drawn perfectly using [World.js](http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/custom/world.js)  but I can't select and scope the map to a specific country [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-vue-demo-cop9z)

The working example without Vue is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/maps/demo/all-maps)

So tried to fetch the geo json data for a country like [Russia](https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/ru/ru-all.geo.json)
The issue is that one is world.js and the other one is returning geo.json

What data/URL should be used to draw country level maps and Is there any Vue example in which we can scope to countries with click?
Where should the country level geojson data be placed in the js so that the country level data is drawn

```
$("#mapDropdown").change(function () {
// Scope to country
}
```

Comment: This thread will be continued here: https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=45389#p161559 In the future - please do not duplicate your questions on the support channels.